# Maya window adding a row dynamically with python

Tags: python, window, row, maya

I've been working on this for a while and I can't find any information about adding a row to a window. I seen it done with pyside2 and qt, witch would work but the users are using multiple versions of Maya (2016 = pyside, 2017=pyside2).

I want it like adding a widget in in pyside. I done it where adding a row is a function like add row 1, add row 2, and add row 3 but the script get to long. I need to parent to `rowColumnLayout` and make that unique in order to delete that later. Also I have to query the textfield in each row. Maybe a `for` loop that adds a number to the row? I really don't know but this is what I have so far:

[image: screenshot of widget]

```
from maya import cmds

def row(  ):
    global fed
    global info
    item=cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, q=True, sl=True)
    if item == 1:
        cam=cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, q=True, v=True)
        fed=cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc = 1)
        cmds.rowLayout(nc=7)
        cmds.text(l= cam )
        cmds.text(l=u'Frame Range  ')
        start = cmds.textField('textField3')
        cmds.text(l=u' to ')
        finish = cmds.textField('textField2')
        cmds.button(l=u'render',c='renderTedd()')
        cmds.button(l=u'delete',c='deleteRow()')
        cmds.setParent (fed)
        def deleteRow ():
                cmds.deleteUI(fed, layout=True)
    if item == 2:
        print item
        global red
        cam1=cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, q=True, v=True)
        red = cmds.rowColumnLayout()
        cmds.rowLayout(nc=7)
        cmds.text(l= cam1 )
        cmds.text(l=u'Frame Range  ')
        start = cmds.textField('textField3')
        cmds.text(l=u' to ')
        finish = cmds.textField('textField2')
        cmds.button(l=u'render',c='renderTedd()')
        cmds.button(l=u'delete',c='deleteRow2()')
        cmds.setParent (red)
def deleteRow2 ():
    cmds.deleteUI(red, control=True)
def cameraInfo():
    info=cmds.optionMenu(mygroup, q=True, sl=True)
    print info
def deleteRow ():
    cmds.deleteUI(fed, control=True)
def getCamera():
    layers=pm.ls(type="renderLayer")
    for layer in layers:
        pm.editRenderLayerGlobals(currentRenderLayer=layer)
        cameras=pm.ls(type='camera')
        for cam in cameras:
            if pm.getAttr(str(cam) + ".renderable"):
                relatives=pm.listRelatives(cam, parent=1)
                cam=relatives[0]
                cmds.menuItem(p=mygroup,label=str (cam) )
window = cmds.window()
cmds.rowColumnLayout(nr=10)
mygroup = cmds.optionMenu( label='Colors', changeCommand='cameraInfo()' )
getCamera()
cmds.button(l=u'create camera',aop=1,c='row ()')
cmds.showWindow( window )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally doable with `cmds.`  The trick is just to structure the code so that the buttons in each row know and can operate on the widgets in that row; once that works you can add rows all day long.

To make it work you want to do two things:

1. *Don't* use the string form of callbacks.  It's never a good idea, for reasons detailed [here](http://blog.theodox.com/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet)
2. *Do* use [closures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-closures/) to make sure your callbacks are referring to the right widgets.  Done right you can do what you want without the overhead of a class.

Basically, this adds up to making a function which generates both the gui items for the row and also generates the callback functions -- the creator function will 'remember' the widgets and the callbacks it creates will have access to the widgets.  Here's a minimal example:

```
def row_test():

    window = cmds.window(title='lotsa rows')
    column = cmds.columnLayout()

    def add_row(cameraname) :
        cmds.setParent(column)
        this_row = cmds.rowLayout(nc=6, cw6 = (72, 72, 72, 72, 48, 48) )
        cmds.text(l= cameraname )
        cmds.text(l=u'Frame Range')
        start = cmds.intField()
        finish = cmds.intField()

        # note: buttons always fire a useless
        # argument; the _ here just ignores
        # that in both of these callback functions
        def do_delete(_):
            cmds.deleteUI(this_row)

        def do_render(_):
            startframe = cmds.intField(start, q=True, v=True)
            endframe = cmds.intField(finish, q=True, v=True)
            print "rendering ", cameraname, "frames", startframe, endframe

        cmds.button(l=u'render',c=do_render)
        cmds.button(l=u'delete',c=do_delete)

    for cam in cmds.ls(type='camera'):
        add_row(cam)


    cmds.showWindow(window)


row_test()
```

By defining the callback functions inside of `add_row()`, they have access to the widgets which get stored as `start` and `finish`.  Even though `start` and `finish` will be created over and over each time the function runs, the values they store are captured by the closures and are still available when you click a button.  They also inherit the value of `cameraname` so the rendering script can get that information as well.

> At the risk of self-advertising: if you need to do serious GUI work using cmds you should check out [mGui](https://github.com/theodox/mGui) -- a python module that makes working with cmds gui less painful for complex projects.

Comment: What about add and subtracting a row?

Comment: If you run the sample, the `delete` button deletes the row that it lives in.  I just added rows for all the cameras in the scene, but you should be able to see how you could create new ones  - the only thing you would need to take `add_row()` outside of `row_test()` is to make `add_row()` take the name of the parent columnLayout as an argument -- they you could add rows as needed.  Deleting a row from code is just calling `cmds.deleteUI` on its rowLayout.